# Get stand out color of UIImage

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uiimage, cgcontext, uicolor

I'm trying to get the color that stands out in a uiimage like I would get a red color if this was the photo:
[image: Red Color]

I know to get the average color i would use the code below but it would return nlack or a gray as the average color I want this code to get that red color.

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        unsigned char rgba[4];
        CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rgba, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1),  artworkImageView.image.CGImage);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
        CGContextRelease(context);
        UIColor *colorOfArtwork;

         if(rgba[3]) {
            CGFloat alpha = ((CGFloat)rgba[3])/255.0;
            CGFloat multiplier = alpha/255.0;
            colorOfArtwork = [UIColor colorWithRed:((CGFloat)rgba[0])*multiplier
                                   green:((CGFloat)rgba[1])*multiplier
                                    blue:((CGFloat)rgba[2])*multiplier
                                   alpha:alpha];
        }
        else {
            colorOfArtwork =  [UIColor colorWithRed:((CGFloat)rgba[0])/255.0
                                   green:((CGFloat)rgba[1])/255.0
                                    blue:((CGFloat)rgba[2])/255.0
                                   alpha:((CGFloat)rgba[3])/255.0];
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something very similar to omz's answer.

1). Iterate through pixels and capture the most frequent colors in a UIImage

2). Iterate over the most frequent colors and find the color that has the highest (value + saturation) sum.

I found out that value(brightness) plus the saturation would work when I visited http://colorizer.org . A saturation of 0 is white and a value of 0 is black. Opposite of these colors I noticed that at around 100% saturation and value is where these stand out colors subsided.

Another option which I tried but returned less favorable results, was to convert it to HSL and retrieve the lightness. In a range from 0 - 100, 50 is where the saturation and value would be 100. So instead of getting the highest sum of saturation and value you would iterate through the colors getting the color with a lightness most close to 50.

My code is below:

```
#import "ImageHelper.h" //Found Here-> https://github.com/fylfot/MostResentColorUIImage/blob/master/MostRecentColor/ImageHelper.h

...

float maxDominatingFactor = 0.0;
UIColor *standOutColor;
NSArray *colors = [ImageHelper mostFrequentColors:30 of:self withColorPallete:ColorPalete512];
for(UIColor *color in colors){
    if(([color brightness] + [color saturation]) > maxDominatingFactor){
        standOutColor = color;
        maxDominatingFactor = ([color brightness] + [color saturation]);
    }
}

//standOutColor is now the stand out color
```

Note: I have a category on UIColor for calculating brightness and saturation.

Here is a project I made for it:

https://github.com/kdogisthebest/StandOutColor

Answer (score 3):

First off, this isn't a trivial problem in most cases. What seems obvious to you as a human can still be very hard to codify in an algorithm because human perception of what "stands out" is quite complex.

If you always have images that are grayscale with only one color, it could be relatively easy, but the same image against a blue sky might be more challenging.

For the image that you've shown, you could iterate over all pixels and convert the colors to [HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV). Then you could only consider pixels above a certain saturation threshold and calculate their average hue. As I said, this will only work in simple cases like your sample image, where there's really only one color and the rest is grayscale. In other cases you might need to take the position of the pixels into consideration (colors near the center perhaps stand out more) and cannot simply take the average hue (clustering the histogram could work).

I won't go into detail here on how to get pixel color values from an image, you'll find several posts about this on SO, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8189445/573626).

Comment: Thanks for the links I was trying to make my app like the color in this one: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cartunes-music-player/id415408192?mt=8